# in Flutter/Dart, is there a way of creating a List that has list items of varying height and starts from a specified item

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-listview, autoscroll, flutter-packages

I am implementing a list that builds its children lazily. This list has items of varying sizes and also needs to start from a specified list item (as opposed to starting from the first or last items). The list is on a tab which is one of a few tabs in a TabBarView. The TabBarView itself is the body of a NestedScrollView. My list should expand and collapse the SliverAppBar as it scrolls.

I have used the [ExtendedNestedScrollView](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_nested_scroll_view) package since i also need to maintain the current scroll position of each tab together with the [ScrollablePositioneList](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list)  package to set an initailScrollIndex the item my list should start from.
**Objectives**

1. List starts from specified item ✅
2. List expands and collapses SliverAppBar when scrolled (currently using the NotificationListener to expand and collapse the SliverAppBar manually)
3. List maintains scroll position when switching between tabs ❌

Comment: The problem is on how you maintain the widget lifecycle when switching tabs, not the list itself

Comment: @DhafinRayhan I am adding the AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin to the tab widgets state classes and passing a unique key to each tab widget.